# Isomorphism between sets

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional Vector Space over $\mathbb{F}_q$ that contain a $k$-dimensional subspace $U$. Now I want to show that the set $\{W:U\subseteq W\subseteq V\}$ is isomorphic to the set $\{W: W\subseteq V/U\}$. Intuitively it is clear but I'm not sure how to do a formal proof.

---

After reading the helpful comment I came up with this but I'm not sure it is correct.

I want to prove that $\{W\:|\:U\subseteq W \subset V\}\cong \{W\:|\:W \subseteq V/U\}$, which means I need to show that there exists invertible map between the two sets. Consider the canonical projection $\pi : \{W\:|\:U\subseteq W \subset V\}\rightarrow \{W\:|\:W \subseteq V/U\}$, defined by $W\mapsto \{w+U\:|\: w\in W\}$. I have to prove that this map $\pi$ has both a right and a left inverse. Define the inverse map by $\pi^{-1} : X \mapsto \{v\in V\:|\: v+U \in X \}$.

Notice that $\pi $ is surjective because $W\subseteq V/U$ is the set $\{w+U\:|\: w\in W\}$ which is exactly by definition $\pi(W)$. Surjectivity of $\pi$ implies $\pi(\pi^{-1}(W))=W$.

So now I need to show that $\pi^{-1}(\pi (W))=W$. The "$\supseteq$"-inclusion is true for any map. To prove the other inclusion, notice that
$\pi^{-1}(\pi (W))=\{v\in V\: |\: v+U\in \pi (W)\}$. So $x\in \{v\in V\: |\: v+U\in \pi (W)\}$ implies that $x+U\in \{w+U\:|\: w\in W\}$ which implies $x\in W$, and the $\subseteq$ inclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

This holds in general. You do not need $V$ to be finite-dimensional and you do not need the field to be specified.

There is an obvious bijection:

Given $W$ with $U \subset W \subset V$, you consider $\{w+U | w \in W \} \subset V/U$.

Given $W$ with $W \subset V/U$, you consider $U \subset \{v \in V | v+U \in W\} \subset V$.

These two maps are inverse to each other.

Note for proving this: With the canonical projection $\pi: V \twoheadrightarrow V/U$, the first map is shortly written as $W \mapsto \pi(W)$ and the second map is shortly written as $W \mapsto \pi^{-1}(W)$.

The fact that $\pi(\pi^{-1}(W)) = W$ holds is then obtained just by surjectivity of $\pi$. So you only need to show $\pi^{-1}(\pi(W))=W$, where the "$\supset$"-inclusion holds for any map, so you only need to show $\pi^{-1}(\pi(W)) \subset W$, which is very easy.

Comment: I thought I had to prove that there exists a bijection between the sets and not an invertible map? I know a bijection is invertible, but is the opposite implication true?

Comment: A bijection is nothing but an invertible map.

Comment: I edited my question, where I tried what you suggested. Does this look like I'm on the right track? I'm a bit unsure about the surjective part.